# Fill Excel column from every 13th row

Tags: excel

I need to fill a column in Sheet1 starting on G112 from Sheet4 starting from D2.

So Sheet1 G112 =Sheet4!D2

G113 would have =Sheet4!D15

and so on.  I also need every 13th row from other columns as well and I don't want to have to copy the reference for every cell I need.  Is there a way to fill a column with every 13th row so I don't need to do it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet4!A"&((ROW()-112)*13)+2)
```

Note: This formula works only of the cell you're inputting it the first time is in row 112. You'll have to adjust it otherwise here:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet4!A"&((ROW()-112)*13)+2)
                             ^^^
```

To adjust the rows to skip each time, adjust here:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet4!A"&((ROW()-112)*13)+2)
                                  ^^
```

And to adjust the offset from the beginning (which is a minimum of 1, otherwise you'll get a reference of `A0`), adjust here:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet4!A"&((ROW()-112)*13)+2)
                                      ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `INDIRECT` function:

If `B1` contains `INDIRECT("A" & C1)` and `C1` contains `6`, `B1` will show the value of the `A6` cell. Using that function, you can put the desired indexes in a column (e.g. C), and extract the values from another column (e.g. A).